# Does HttpAuthenticationContext.Principal will be dispose automatically when request has finished?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a question about `IAuthenticationFilter` implementation in ASP.NET Web API.

I have implement `IAuthenticationFilter` that return a custom `IPrincipal` that also implement `IDisposable`. Does the `IPrincipal` that I returned will be dispose automatically when the request has been finished?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`IPrincipal` interface doesn't implement `IDisposable`, so Web API is not aware of your implementation detail. So no, it will not be disposed after request.

Comment: Thank for reply. But I mean Web API will be detect `IDisposable` and dispose it automatically.